# I want to save with shared preference but the app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to make an app that basically the user inputs some strings inside a

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/texto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#4249ff"
            android:hint="@string/BtnO"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="confirmInput"
        android:text="@string/Btns" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So when the user presses the confirm button I want it to be saved but the app crashes instead its the first time I'm using shared preferences and I don't really understand it.I doesn't save the value the user.Also I know I have used hint but with my shared preferences it changes the hint into a text instead of it staying like that.
Here is my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText nameInput;
    private EditText homeInput;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences prefs= getSharedPreferences("my_data",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = prefs.getString("MY_NAME","name");
        String home = prefs.getString("MY_HOME","home");

        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto)).setText(name);
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.textd)).setText(home);

        nameInput =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto);
        nameInput =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textd);

    }

    public void copy(View view) {
    }

    public void confirmInput(View view) {
        String name=nameInput.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("MY_NAME",name);
        editor.apply();
    }
    public void confirmInput2(View view) {
        String home=homeInput.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("MY_HOME",home);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should start by getting the stack trace from the Android logcat. This will tell you which line of code causes the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is because there are two declarations of `SharedPreferences prefs` one in the `onCreate` method level and another in the beginning of the class

The error would be fix just by removing the prefs declaration `onCreate` and just use the variable defined in the beginning of the class as below

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Take a look here!
    this.prefs= getSharedPreferences("my_data",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String name = prefs.getString("MY_NAME","name");
    String home = prefs.getString("MY_HOME","home");

    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto)).setText(name);
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.textd)).setText(home);

    nameInput =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto);
    nameInput =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textd);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make this minor change:

```
    prefs= 
         getSharedPreferences("my_data",MODE_PRIVATE);
         String name=prefs.getString("MY_NAME","name");
```

Instead of

```
      SharedPreferences prefs= 
       getSharedPreferences("my_data",MODE_PRIVATE);
       String name = prefs.getString("MY_NAME","name");
```

You have already defined sharedpref object globally. You dont need to again create it.